Where to buy drywall electrical mounting brackets
I have some brackets like this in a 1997 trailer home, I guess for reinforcing electrical outlets in places where just drywall wasn't enough.

Any idea where I could buy more or something like it, for reinforcing some RV style outlets:


RV repair supplier? That doesn't look like something I would use in a house...
